# calculating average of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on an angular app. I have an array as follow:

```
data = [
{
 num1:12.233,
 num2: 13.345
},
{
 num1:10.233,
 num2: 23.345
},
{
 num1:18.233,
 num2: 33.345
}
]
```

Similarly at runtime time I can have many elements. I want to traverse array such that I can add all the num1 and divide them by number of num1 present. For example, I want to write a code which can take num1 from every element

```
12.233 + 10.233 + 18.233 / 3(total num1 elements in array)
```

Similarly for num2.

How can I do that?

Comment: why won't you use a for loop (from 0 to length of the array or use foreach) to sum it up and divide it by length of array?

Comment: const avg = data.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue.num1, 0) / data.length;

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the total of elements and then divide it with `data.length`

```js
const data = [
  {
    num1: 12.233,
    num2: 13.345,
  },
  {
    num1: 10.233,
    num2: 23.345,
  },
  {
    num1: 18.233,
    num2: 33.345,
  },
];

const avg = data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.num1, 0) / data.length;
console.log(avg);
```

For average of `num2` then you can similarly do as:

```
const avg = data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.num2, 0) / data.length;
```

---

You can also get the `average` using a `single iteration` as:

```js
const data = [
  {
    num1: 12.233,
    num2: 13.345,
  },
  {
    num1: 10.233,
    num2: 23.345,
  },
  {
    num1: 18.233,
    num2: 33.345,
  },
];

const [avgNum1, avgNum2] = data
  .reduce((acc, curr) => [acc[0] + curr.num1, acc[1] + curr.num2], [0, 0])
  .map((n) => n / data.length);
console.log(avgNum1, avgNum2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through `data` and add the values of `num1` and `num2` to a variable, then divide it by the length of `data` (which is 3).

```js
const data = [
  {
    num1: 12.233,
    num2: 13.345
  },
  {
    num1: 10.233,
    num2: 23.345
  },
  {
    num1: 18.233,
    num2: 33.345
  }
]

let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  num1 += data[i].num1;
  num2 += data[i].num2;
}

const num1Avg = num1 / data.length;
const num2Avg = num2 / data.length;
console.log(`Average of num1: ${num1Avg}`)
console.log(`Average of num2: ${num2Avg}`)
```

Answer (score -1):

let avg = data.reduce(
(accumVariable, curValue) => accumVariable + curValue.num1
, 0
) / data.length

Comment: Did you just copy this from below?

Comment: no , after i posted i found similar answer